# Get list of items from firestore in react native/[Unhandled promise rejection: FirebaseError: Expected type 'ba', but it was: a custom Oa object]

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, expo

Hi there i need to get from my firestore db a list of items like this

```
items={{
    '2012-05-22': [{name: 'item 1 - any js object'}],
    '2012-05-23': [{name: 'item 2 - any js object', height: 80}],
    '2012-05-24': [],
    '2012-05-25': [{name: 'item 3 - any js object'}, {name: 'any js object'}]
  }}
```

This is my db structure[image: firestore db structure]

So this is my code to do it but isnt working

```
const getUserEvents = () => {
  const FSquery = query( collection( FSdb, `usertasks/${user.uid}/events`) )
  const unsubscribe = onSnapshot( FSquery, ( querySnapshot ) => {
  // get all documents (using the date as id) from user's events collection
  let eventData = {}
  querySnapshot.forEach( (doc) => {
    console.log("testing id", doc.id)

  let arr = []
  // the id of the document is the date for the event
  eventData[ doc.id ] = arr
  console.log("testing array", arr)
  console.log("testing eventdata", eventData)

  })
  // now we get the collection of events for each day
  let eventsOfTheDay = []
  const eventKeys = Object.keys( eventData )
  eventKeys.map( async (eventDate) => {
  const events = await getDocs( FSdb, `users/${user.uid}/events/${eventDate}/items`)
  events.forEach( (doc) => {
  let event = doc.data()
  event.id = doc.id
  eventsOfTheDay.push( event )
  })
  
  eventData[ eventDate ] = eventsOfTheDay
  console.log("this are the eventsoftheday", eventsOfTheDay)

  })
  // now we can set it into a state that can be passed to components to be consumed by the calendar
  // eg setEvents( eventData )
  })
  }
```

I dont get any value from eventsoftheday not even the consloge string "this is eventsoftheday"
Thanks
i get this error
[Unhandled promise rejection: FirebaseError: Expected type 'ba', but it was: a custom Oa object]

Comment: maybe I'm being dumb here, but the path in code is `users/${user.uid}/events/${eventDate}/dayEvents` and it looks like from the console image that the path is `userTasks/${user.uid}/events/${eventDate}/items`

Comment: yeh you are right i changed and still doesnt work. Gonna edit the post to change it. Thanks. Im getting this error [Unhandled promise rejection: FirebaseError: Expected type 'ba', but it was: a custom Oa object]

Comment: That sounds like an error related to a write operation.

Answer (score 1):

The `getDocs` function takes a [Query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_.query) as the only parameter but you are passing two.

```
const events = await getDocs(FSdb, `users/${user.uid}/events/${eventDate}/items`)
```

Try changing the above line to like this:

```
const events = await getDocs(
  collection(FSdb, `users/${user.uid}/events/${eventDate}/items`)
);
// ^^^
// add collection
```